# SVG foreign object is not getting displayed using D3

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am using D3 render a simple network diagram. And in each node I want to display html content for that foreign object is used. Foreign object is having html inside.  The network is getting rendered. But I am not able to view the html content anybody know why it is not rendering the html?

I am using below code.

```
  dom.svg.selectAll('.node').append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
  .append("xhtml:body").append("xhtml:p")
    .style("color", "red")
.text("Object in SVG");
```

Here is the  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/DVw3P/)

Answer (score 4):

You can't append `foreignObjects` (or indeed anything) to `circle` elements. Instead, append them to a container element like `g`s for example. Fixed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DVw3P/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there any way place the foreignobject over the circle so that the circle is not visible?

Comment: You could just not append the circles and move the text so it appears more in the middle: http://jsfiddle.net/DVw3P/2/

Comment: Thanks its working.  I have made it with html div http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/9faWA/     is there any way I can place the edge of div eaxactly on the intersection of two SVG lines?

Comment: Many thanks, I was near to cry, now all is working 

XD